# Unable to import my own class into another class

Tags: java, arrays, import, foreach

I am coding in blueJ. My objectives are this: 
1)Write a User class

A User:

```
has a username e.g 'fj3'
has a userType which can be: 'user', 'editor' or 'admin'
has a name e.g 'Francis'
has a constructor which takes the username, userType and name as parameters
has a getUsername() method
has a getUserType() method
has a getName() method
has a setUserType() method which takes one of the user types as a parameter
```

2)Write a UserGroup class

-The UserGroup class must have an ArrayList of Users.

Write a constructor for the UserGroup class. It should instantiate the ArrayList.

In UserGroup write a method called .addSampleData() which creates 10 Users and using the ArrayList's add() method put the 10 new User objects into the ArrayList.

In UserGroup write a getUser method which takes an int as a parameter and returns the User in that slot of the ArrayList.

In UserGroup write a printUsernames() method in UserGroup:

Using an enhanced for loop (see above), loop through the ArrayList and print the username and userType of each user in the ArrayList.

What I have so far is:

```
package user;
public class User{
     public enum UserType{                           
        ADMIN, EDITOR, USER;
     }

     private String id;                             
     private UserType userPermissions;               
     private String actualName;                      

     public User(String username, UserType userType, String name){
         id = username;
         userPermissions = userType;
         actualName= name;
     } 

    public String getUsername(){
        return id;
    }

    public UserType getUserType(){
        return userPermissions;
    }       

    public String getName(){
        return actualName;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType input){
        userPermissions = input;
    }
}
```

And my UserGroup class:

```
package user;
import java.util.*;
import user.User.UserType; 

public class UserGroup{

    private ArrayList<User> people;

    public UserGroup(){
        people = new Arraylist<User>();
    }

    public static void addSampleData(String username, UserType userType, String name){
        People.add(new User(username, userType,name));
    }

    public String getUser(int list){
        return User; 
    }

    public void printUsernames(){
        for (User user: groupArray){
            System.out.printf("%s %s\n", user.getUsername(), user.getuserType);
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously far from being complete but I am completely stuck. My first problem is that "for (User user : groupArray)" is giving me the error illegal start of type. Please help me with this!! I think my User class is fine but my UserGroup class is nowhere enar completing all the objectives and I don't know how to do them!!

Comment: Your use of "Package" in your import seems suspicious: `import package.User.UserType;` as usually this would be `import User.UserType;` (although package names by convention usually begin with lower-case letters). Are these two classes in fact held in different packages? Can you include your package statements with your code?

Comment: Note that I changed your question's subject title to one that tries to reflect what your actual problem is. You would do well to do the same with your next question. Your prior question heading, `Very new to Java- need a lot of assistance with this code` was singularly unhelpful as it tells us nothing about what your main problem is.

Comment: thank you- when I removed package that compiling error went but there are still many other problems with this code which I cannot figure out how to fix. Now that the importing error is fixed is there a way I can change my subject title to reflect my new issues?

Comment: You should ask only one specific question per question on this site. I would try to work through each problem one at a time, in isolation if possible, in order to solve the overall problem.

Comment: Two things:  You've edited much of your original question, which invalidates a lot of the older answers.  Instead of adding the code which you've fixed to the question, indicate that you've resolved parts of the issues, and if need be, add that code to the question as well.  Second, `UserGroup` has no property `groupArray`; how does this compile?

Comment: I will do that from now on- I am new to the forum and there was so much that needed changing I thought if I simply added it in the question would get rather cumbersome and unreadable. Also it does not compile- one of my many issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The specification requires a `UserGroup`'s list of users to be
   instantiated within the constructor. Thus, it should be not be
   static but an instance variable:

   ```
   public class UserGroup {

       private ArrayList<User> people;

       public UserGroup() {
           people = new ArrayList<User>();
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

   This way, you can create multiple `UserGroup` instances, each having their own list of users. With a static variable, this would not be possible.
2. Your `getUser(int)` method does not do what it is supposed to do and
   will not compile. You are returning the type `User` there instead of
   a specific `User` instance.
3. The enhanced for loop you use for printing user names is a free floating block of code. It should be inside the method `printUsernames()` as prescribed by your specification.
4. Your `User` class will work fine, but its instance variables should be `private` instead of `public`.
5. To resolve your import issues, put your `User` class into a package, e.g. `user`, and have `UserGroup` import `User.UserType` (the "User." part is needed since `UserType` is an inner class within `User`) from this package.

   ```
   package user;
   public class User{
   // ...
   }

   package user;
   import java.util.*; 
   import user.User.UserType;

   public class UserGroup{
   // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I have made the changes you have suggested and edited my original post to reflect these but I get the error message "cannot find symbol- class Arraylist" on the line " people = new ArrayList<User>(); " when I try to compile. Also how would I go about editing my code to return a specific user instance rather than the type user? You've been a massive help so far- Thank you!!

Comment: Note the lowercase "L" in the error message: "cannot find symbol- class Array**l**ist". It has to be "ArrayList<User>" with an uppercase "L".

Comment: For returning the right user instance, use your list's [get method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)).

Comment: ah that explains it- I'll have to be more careful with capitilisation in the future!! For the get method I have tried public User get(int index){
        return User;
    }
but this is not working! where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through the users in the arraylist, your enhanced for loop should be like this:

```
for (User user: groupArray)
    System.out.printf("%s %s\n", user.getUsername(), user.getuserType);
```

EDIT:
To adhere more effectively to the question and to be more conventional, the ArrayList should be declared then instantiated after.

```
private static ArrayList<User> UserGroup;

public UserGroup() {
    UserGroup = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code to do what you have said so far but "for (User user: groupArray)" is giving me a compiling error of illegal start of type. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: so 
UserGroup.toArray(){
     System.out.printf("%s %s\n", user.getUsername(), user.getuserType);
}
?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of "Package" in your import seems suspicious:

```
import package.User.UserType;
```

as usually this would be

```
import User.UserType;
```

or actually more commonly:

```
import user.UserType;
```

since package names by convention should begin with a lower-case letter.

In the future, please be sure to include your package statements with your code if the package name is relevant to the question.